# Querying REPEATED records in Bigquery and cloud datalab

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table EMP which has Empno, Name , Age as general fields.

EMP.Salary as RECORD with Repeated type with two fields Month & Amt

```
EmpNo: 1
Age : 25
Name : Alex

Salary.Month : Jan
Salary.Amt : 2000

Salary.Month : Feb
Salary.Amt : 3000

Salary.Month : Mar
Salary.Amt : 3500

Emp No: 2
Age : 26
Name : Teresa

Salary.Month : Jan
Salary.Amt : 1000

Salary.Month : Feb
Salary.Amt : 2000

Salary.Month : Mar
Salary.Amt : 3000
```

How can I use standard sql in Bigquery to fetch these repeated items ?

Regards, Siva

Comment: what exactly you mean by fetch here? can you show expected result to make it clear?

Comment: below? you mean exactly as it is in question? if so - you should revisit what you want as this usually makes not much sense! the question you should ask to yourself is  - why I think i need it this way? what /how I will use it then? etc. You might want to calculate sum of all Amounts? or something else? this would make much more sense

Comment: I need the biqQuery for following output.


EmpNo  Name   Month   Salary

1        Alex          Jan  2000
1 Alex  Feb  3000
1 Alex  Mar  3500
2 Teresa  Jan  1000
2 Teresa  Feb  2000
2  Teresa  Feb  3000

Comment: ok @mikhail. I need the details of empno, name and sum of salary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I need the biqQuery for following output. EmpNo Name Month Salary 1   Alex    Jan 2000 1  Alex    Feb 3000 1  Alex Mar    3500 2  Teresa  Jan 1000 2  Teresa  Feb 2000 2 Teresa   Feb 3000

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT EmpNo, Age, Name, s.*
FROM `project.dataset.your_table` t, UNNEST(Salary) s
```

You can test / play with it using dummy data from your question as below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.your_table` AS (
  SELECT 1 EmpNo, 25 Age, 'Alex' Name, 
    [STRUCT<Month STRING, Amt INT64>('Jan', 2000), ('Feb', 3000), ('Mar', 3500)] Salary UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 26, 'Teresa',
    [STRUCT<Month STRING, Amt INT64>('Jan', 1000), ('Feb', 2000), ('Mar', 3000)] 
)
SELECT EmpNo, Age, Name, s.*
FROM `project.dataset.your_table` t, UNNEST(Salary) s
```

and result is

```
Row EmpNo   Age Name    Month   Amt  
1   1       25  Alex    Jan     2000     
2   1       25  Alex    Feb     3000     
3   1       25  Alex    Mar     3500     
4   2       26  Teresa  Jan     1000     
5   2       26  Teresa  Feb     2000     
6   2       26  Teresa  Mar     3000
```

> I need the details of empno, name and sum of salary

In case if you need SUM of salary you can use below  example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.your_table` AS (
  SELECT 1 EmpNo, 25 Age, 'Alex' Name, 
    [STRUCT<Month STRING, Amt INT64>('Jan', 2000), ('Feb', 3000), ('Mar', 3500)] Salary UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 26, 'Teresa',
    [STRUCT<Month STRING, Amt INT64>('Jan', 1000), ('Feb', 2000), ('Mar', 3000)] 
)
SELECT EmpNo, Age, Name, 
  (SELECT SUM(Amt) FROM UNNEST(Salary)) Total
FROM `project.dataset.your_table`
```

and result is

```
Row EmpNo   Age Name    Total    
1   1       25  Alex    8500     
2   2       26  Teresa  6000
```

Comment: Thank you @Mikhail. It works well for sum of salary. Suppose, if i have additional column in salary records as 'Tax', can i get sum of tax as well along with sum of salary ?

Comment: I prefer to write cross join of two tables with the actual syntax CROSS JOIN (as opposed to implicit cross join via comma).  In your answer it's written as FROM `project.dataset.your_table` t, UNNEST(Salary) s --> I would write it as FROM `project.dataset.your_table` as t CROSS JOIN UNNEST(Salary) as s

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT EmpNo, Age, Name, 
  (SELECT SUM(Amt) FROM UNNEST(Salary)) Total
FROM `project.dataset.your_table`
```

This worked well.